# How do I set up DynDNS on my MacBook?

Tags: remote-control, dns

I want to create a host name that points to my MacBook dynamically, so I can have a chance to take back the control if it was stolen. I opened ssh and vnc, but I have no idea how to find my machine. Maybe DynDNS is a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to [www.dyndns.com](http://www.dyndns.com/) and register.  Then [install the dynamic updater on your Mac](http://www.dyndns.com/support/clients/mac.html) and [follow the installation instructions](http://www.dyndns.com/support/clients/dyndns-updater-guide-mac.html).  This will then connect to [www.dyndns.com](http://www.dyndns.com/) and update your DNS information whenever your Mac is connected to the internet.  You could then use SSH or other means to log onto your Mac from an iPhone or other computer/Mac by connecting to the URL (e.g. - mymacbook.dyndns.com) you select upon registering on dyndns.com.

There are another couple of steps.  You need to get your broadband router to forward traffic coming in on specific ports to your Mac.  You should be able to find a how-to on [www.portforward.com](http://www.portforward.com/) for your router model. You also need to setup a static IP for your Mac which is best done on your router.  Your routers documentation should tell you how to do this.

Comment: Just FYI http://www.no-ip.com has the same service :)

Comment: Note that whilst this should work, there is every chance it might only work while the scurvy dog is still in your wifi range...  Once it's moved elsewhere, and is on someone else's network with someone else's port forwarding and mapping settings etc, there is no guarantee you will be able to communicate with it.  It's may be better to have some way of it communicating with you, but I haven't the time to look into such software yet, so just leaving this as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (a bit more pricey) in addition to the one suggested by Griffo's would be signing up for MobileMe ("Back to my Mac").

Or if you are by chance operating your own domain name server somewhere, you can set up dynamic DNS there yourself through the `Sharing->Edit...` tab.